# how to make superset display druid data?

Tags: druid, apache-superset

I have been trying to have superset display data from druid, but was unable to succeed.
In my druid console I could clearly see a "wiki-edits" data source, but, when I have specified druid cluster and druid data source in superset, it did not pick up any of that data.
Have anyone been able to make this work?

Comment: Can you update your question with what you have tried and any error messages you get?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Refresh Druid Metadata` option available in the source menu of Superset.

If even after that you are not able to see the data source then make sure you have given the correct `coordinator host,port` and `broker host,port` in the Druid Cluster source of Superset.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `scan for new datasources` in the Sources Menu?